Quicker Way To Mask Areas Of Polygon Mesh
For 3D texturing projects I often need to mask certain areas around a mesh. To do this, I currently need to use the pen tool and create paths. But this is a pretty time-consuming process. Using the magic wand tool will create selections but then I don't have control over removing sections. Here is an example image and workflow.

I have a UV map as a layer
I need to create a path around one of the UV islands as close to the border as possible
After creating the path I contract it and then feather it so that I
have a more natural transition

Blank UV Map

After Selection

I would imagine there is a more clever way to make my selections, but my attempts at using the magic wand or other selection tools have failed. Thanks for any advice you might have!

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  The magic wand tool won't work well on such images because there is a lack of contrast.   Perhaps you could create a high contrast version for the purpose of making selections, and then remove it afterwards.

Is it really necessary to mask it precisely? I'd think anything out of the mesh bounds won't show up anywhere in the 3D object.

Thanks for the welcome and comments! Billy let me see if I can get a more contrasty version. @luciano I need to mask because I'm essentially feathering in the content in these selections. The selection will become an alpha mask and so my displacement or bump, etc, will not have a hard edge start at the UV seam.

You will get better results if you export a UV map with more contrast. Apply a solid color material to your model (looking at your images, probably a white material would be best), bake it and export the resulting UV map. Then you'll have white blocks of color against a black background.
From there you can easily select with either magic wand  or color range, for example. After that you should have no trouble shrinking + feathering the selection.

Bingo. Thank you! This is going to save time in this workflow, I really appreciate the quick answer!

@K_C no problem! Sometimes the easiest solution is to go back to the beginning of the workflow and fix it there :)
